# WCSession didReceive file not movable "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch, connectivity

After transferring a file from iPhone to Apple Watch I get the Error

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

What do I do wrong? These are the code snippets:

**iPhone ViewController**

```
func makeAction () {
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: fileArray[0].object(at: 2) as! String)
    var applicationDict = Dictionary<String, Array<AnyObject>>()
    applicationDict["fileArray"] = fileArray
    WCSession.default().transferFile(url, metadata: applicationDict)
}
```

**Watch InterfaceController**

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceive file: WCSessionFile) {
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
    print("RECEIVED")
    var applicationDict = Dictionary<String, Array<AnyObject>>()
    applicationDict = file.metadata as! Dictionary<String, Array<AnyObject>>
    self.fileArray = applicationDict["fileArray"]!
    self.fileList = self.fileArray

    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let tempDocsDir = dirPaths[0] as String
    let docsDir = tempDocsDir.appending("/")
    let filemgr = FileManager.default

    do {
        let fileName = self.fileArray[0].object(at: 1) as! String
        try filemgr.moveItem(atPath: file.fileURL.path, toPath: docsDir + fileName)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error moving file: \(error.description)")
    }
    self.loadTableData()
})
}
```

**Full Error Message**

> Error moving file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4
>   "“5d1392cd-acac-4b99-abf5-50062e12dc14_95de54df-69b1-43df-bb90-cfac6fed3677.mp3” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn't
>   exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist."
>   UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/pknapp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/950FC0DA-C245-4326-8777-80CE765AF655/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/73C0D94F-483C-4426-B052-001E8837D83A/Documents/Inbox/com.apple.watchconnectivity/FCE7E6CB-2452-4E0A-9AFF-F5B3A51A0DE8/Files/0B96CCB0-A2E1-418B-9859-97C22238A5F5/5d1392cd-acac-4b99-abf5-50062e12dc14_95de54df-69b1-43df-bb90-cfac6fed3677.mp3, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move ), NSFilePath=/Users/pknapp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/950FC0DA-C245-4326-8777-80CE765AF655/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/73C0D94F-483C-4426-B052-001E8837D83A/Documents/Inbox/com.apple.watchconnectivity/FCE7E6CB-2452-4E0A-9AFF-F5B3A51A0DE8/Files/0B96CCB0-A2E1-418B-9859-97C22238A5F5/5d1392cd-acac-4b99-abf5-50062e12dc14_95de54df-69b1-43df-bb90-cfac6fed3677.mp3, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/pknapp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/950FC0DA-C245-4326-8777-80CE765AF655/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/73C0D94F-483C-4426-B052-001E8837D83A/Documents/5d1392cd-acac-4b99-abf5-50062e12dc14_95de54df-69b1-43df-bb90-cfac6fed3677.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b776110 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2
>   "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`didReceiveFile`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615651-session) notes:

> File: The object containing the URL of the file and any additional information. If you want to keep the file referenced by this parameter, **you must move it synchronously to a new location during your implementation of this method. If** you do not move the file, the system deletes it after this method returns.

So make sure to not async in this method before moving the file to a location your app has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it. putting this in an async dispatch was wrong. Without ist -> work perfectly. Please go ahead, nothing to see here :)